# How to put a group of integers in a row in a text file into a list?

Tags: python, text, split, list-comprehension

I have a text file composed mostly of numbers something like this:

```
3  011236547892X
9  02321489764 Q
4  031246547873B
```

I would like to extract each of the following (spaces 5 to 14 (counting from zero)) into a list:

```
1236547892
321489764 
1246547873
```

(Please note: each "number" is 10 "characters" long - the second row has a space at the end.)

and then perform analysis on the contents of each list.

I have umpteen versions, however I think I am closest with:

```
with open('k_d_m.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            range = line.split()
            num_lst = [x for x in range(3,10)]

print(num_lst)
```

However I have: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

What is the best way forward?

What I want to do with num_lst is, amongst other things, as follows:

num_lst = list(map(int, str(num)))

print(num_lst)

nth = 2

odd_total = sum(num_lst[0::nth])
even_total = sum(num_lst[1::nth])
print(odd_total)
print(even_total)

if odd_total - even_total == 0 or odd_total - even_total == 11:
print("The number is ok")
else:
print("The number is not ok")

Comment: "spaces 5 to 14" translates directly to `line[5:15]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple slice:

```
with open('k_d_m.txt') as f:
    num_lst = [x[5:15] for x in f]
```

Response to comment:

```
with open('k_d_m.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        num_lst = list(line[5:15])
        print(num_lst)
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, unfortunately all the numbers are included in one list.  I need each number and only that number to be in num_lst.  I then perform analysis on the number and then do the next one

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the expected output (as a valid python object)?

Comment: Hi Mozway, after reading a row I would like to have a list like this: num_lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2]

Comment: This I use as input into the following:

num_lst = list(map(int, str(num)))

print(num_lst)

nth = 2

odd_total = sum(num_lst[0::nth])
even_total = sum(num_lst[1::nth])
print(odd_total)
print(even_total)

if odd_total - even_total == 0 or odd_total - even_total == 11:
    print("The number is ok")
else:
    print("The number is not ok")

Comment: Comments are not good to post multi-line code, please edit the question. Anyway, check my update for the ground principle

Comment: Sorry Mozway, I don't seem to have been able to get the code formatted nicely

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't name your variable `range`, because that is already taken for the `range()` function. You can easily get the 5 to 14th chars of a string using string[5:15]. Try this:

```
num_lst = []
with open('k_d_m.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        num_lst.append(line[5:15])
print(num_lst)
```

Comment: Hi Erik, unfortunately all the numbers are included in one list.  I need each number and only that number to be in num_lst.  I then perform analysis on the number / num_lst and then do the next one